# How to publish artifacts from Jenkins to uDeploy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, ucd

How to publish artifacts after a successful build from Jenkins to uDeploy (IBM)?

I heard that urbandeploypublisher.hpi is required to upload this API in Jenkins but I didn't find any where.

Comment: First Google result: https://github.com/UrbanCode/jenkins-udeploy-plugin

Comment: It looks like it can be found here: https://www.ibmdw.net/urbancode/plugin/jenkins-ibmucd/

Comment: Hi Phani, you may also want to consider using an artifact repository tool like Nexus or Artifactory to archive and manager your artifacts instead of uDeploy. Your Jenkins build can archive your artifacts in Nexus for example and uDeploy can then fetch the artifact from Nexus and execute necessary deploy steps.

Answer (score 2):

Latest copy of the Plugin for UrbanCode Deploy is available here: https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/plugin/jenkins/

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. There is a plugin IBM UrbanCode Plugin available which you can integrate in Jenkins.

Below is the link you can see the plugin :-
https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/plugins/

1.1.0 is the stable version that you can use. Just by integrating the plugin in Jenkins you would be able to fetch the recent build (code builded by jenkins) from your Urbancode application.

This should work...

Comment: Inside one Jenkins' job, how can I publish to three UCD components? e.g. to app1_web, app1_ear, app1_db.

Answer (score 0):

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21664334 is the URL for the detailed steps to integrate IBM UCD and Jenkins
 (It might be useful for who is trying to integrate UCD and Jenkins)

Jenkins stage for UCD deploy

```
 stage ('UCD Deploy') {
        steps {
            script {
                ucdDeploy {
                    ucdUsername="UCD_username"
                    ucdPassword="UCD_password"
                    applicationName="application_name"
                    environmentName="environment_name"
                    processName="UCD_process_name"
                    artifactVersion= "UCD_component_name : application_version_to_deploy"
                    customProps=""
                }
            }
        }
}
```